# cocoa-touch dependency injection and loading code dynamically

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa-design-patterns

I'm looking into porting an existing enterprise app to iPad. One of the key requirements is that there is a basic functioning app that needs to be highly customizable/extensible. Also, the people working on the customizations and extensions are not part of the product team and do not have access to the base product's code (only interfaces, docs and the binaries). To achieve this, the current application uses a component based architecture where well defined components are used to compose the UI. For a given customer any of these components can be either extended and used instead of the out of the box ones or simply swapped with a new component that adheres to the interface.

Are there libraries in cocoa-touch that support a component model architecture ? (composing the app through a registry/configuration that can easily edited by others than the team developers)

Sebi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you can create a root view controller and inject polymorphic children with:  https://github.com/jasperblues/Typhoon